# Calculating the interval to subsequent occurrences

Tags: r

I have a data contains True and False events, with Date. I want to calculate the interval of next occurrence of False from True in Months e.g if  "677937607    TRUE    25-09-2018" is one record and "677937607    FALSE   25-10-2018" is another, then the difference must be 1M(or fraction).

The expected output is

```
 "677937607 FALSE   03-10-2018  0.something(number of months in fraction)"
    "677937607  FALSE   11-10-2018  0.something(number of months in fraction)"
    "677937607  FALSE   25-10-2018  0.something(number of months in fraction)"
    "677937607  FALSE   07-11-2018  0.something(number of months in fraction)".
 and So on ....

ID          T/F     Date
677937607   FALSE   14-11-2018
677937607   FALSE   01-03-2019
677937607   FALSE   22-01-2019
677937607   FALSE   11-10-2018
677937607   FALSE   29-12-2018
677937607   FALSE   15-02-2019
677937607   FALSE   25-10-2018
677937607   FALSE   25-12-2018
677937607   FALSE   11-03-2019
677937607   FALSE   28-11-2018
677937607   FALSE   05-04-2019
677937607   FALSE   03-10-2018
677937607   FALSE   16-03-2019
677937607   TRUE    25-09-2018
677937607   FALSE   07-11-2018
```

Comment: How is `25-10-2018` next entry after `25-09-2018` ? Shouldn't it be `03-10-2018` ?

Comment: It was just a case picked to show next entry just a month later(but yes from data set it must be 03-10-2018), so corrected expected output. Also the results will something (0.somthing) as it will be somedays in months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this, however, there is no easy (one) way to calculate number of months between two dates so I have considered every month to be of 30 days. You may change it according to your requirements. We create a new group (`gr`) based on `TRUE` values in `T/F` column and then subtract `Date` from the `first` `Date` in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  arrange(ID, Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(gr = cumsum(`T/F`)) %>%
  group_by(gr, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.integer(Date - first(Date))/30) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-gr)

# A tibble: 15 x 4
#          ID `T/F` Date        diff
#       <int> <lgl> <date>     <dbl>
# 1 677937607 TRUE  2018-09-25 0    
# 2 677937607 FALSE 2018-10-03 0.267
# 3 677937607 FALSE 2018-10-11 0.533
# 4 677937607 FALSE 2018-10-25 1    
# 5 677937607 FALSE 2018-11-07 1.43 
# 6 677937607 FALSE 2018-11-14 1.67 
# 7 677937607 FALSE 2018-11-28 2.13 
# 8 677937607 FALSE 2018-12-25 3.03 
# 9 677937607 FALSE 2018-12-29 3.17 
#10 677937607 FALSE 2019-01-22 3.97 
#11 677937607 FALSE 2019-02-15 4.77 
#12 677937607 FALSE 2019-03-01 5.23 
#13 677937607 FALSE 2019-03-11 5.57 
#14 677937607 FALSE 2019-03-16 5.73 
#15 677937607 FALSE 2019-04-05 6.4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 
677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 
677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L, 677937607L), 
`T/F` = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), Date = structure(c(7L, 
1L, 10L, 6L, 15L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 11L, 
4L), .Label = c("01-03-2019", "03-10-2018", "05-04-2019", 
"07-11-2018", "11-03-2019", "11-10-2018", "14-11-2018", "15-02-2019", 
"16-03-2019", "22-01-2019", "25-09-2018", "25-10-2018", "25-12-2018", 
"28-11-2018", "29-12-2018"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Thanks again Ronak for wonderful script, This is ok(if we take number of days as 30 in a month, as i need tentative interval).